# "hit rock bottom" and "upholstered"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms

Can you guys help me figure out what "hit rock bottom" and "upholstered" means in this context?

> You're hardly the rehab-type and besides, you like it too much (drugs). Addicts don't give up until they **hit rock bottom**, and you never will. You're too **upholstered**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dialogue from Patrick Melrose TV adaptation. To hit rock bottom is to sink as low as it is possible to go, to be as unhappy or degraded as someone can be. A ship that sinks will arrive at the bottom of the sea and can go no further. If the sea bottom has rocks present then the wreck may be damaged by these. A drug addict who hits rock bottom will have no hope left and no morals or self respect. He or she will steal from mother's purse, mug old ladies etc. to get money to buy drugs to avoid cold turkey (q.v.).   To be upholstered is literally to be padded as is furniture; figuratively it means to comfortably situated in life (Melrose is rich), and so protected from e.g. starvation or homelessness. The amount of money needed to maintain a drug habit is more than an ordinary person can find normally, but easy for a rich person.